# d3 how to bind data to arc?

Tags: d3.js, pie-chart

I'm new to d3 and would like some guidance in mapping a series of arcs or pie charts to my data. I have a CSV dataset and for each line from the CSV i want to create an arc or a pie chart using the CSV data to determine the radius size etc. 
For example if i have a dataset containing:

> ```
>    arcName, startAngle, endAngle, r
>    arc1, 0, 5, 2
>    arc2, 1, 2, 5
> ```

I want this to produce 2 arcs, one with a radius of 2 and another with a radius of 5 since there are 2 object lines in my CSV file. Is there a way that I can create 2 arcs by mapping my data to the CSV file? Thanks.

Comment: You would need two arc generators for this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Does that mean that if I had a large CSV file containing 300+ lines, I would need to create 300 arc generators? :/

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you would need a separate one for every line. These can certainly be created from the data though.